# Button not highlighting the text

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jQuery snippet, I have stored the variables to highlight them.

```
    var words= ['Sample','count'];
    var keywords = ['import','public','class','static','void','for','if','else'];
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if (#showVariables).click(function(){
        var wordsHtml = $('#identifier').html();
        $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
        var reg = new RegExp(word, 'g');
        wordsHtml = wordsHtml.replace(reg, '<span class="highlight">' + word + '</span>');
        })
        $('#identifier').html(wordsHtml);
    });


});
```

This is the html which might help,

```
<div id="menuDiv"><span id="showVariables" class="button">Variables</span><span id="showKeywords" class="button">Keywords</span></div>
<div id="codeDiv">
<br><span class="keyword">import</span> java.io.*;
<br>
<br><span class="keyword">public</span> <span class="keyword">class</span> <span class="identifier">Sample</span> {

<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="keyword">public</span> <span class="keyword">static</span> <span class="keyword">void</span> main(String args[]) {
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>int</span> <span class="identifier">count</span> = 0;
```

I am trying to highlight keywords and identifiers. Where I might be wrong?

Comment: `if (#showVariables)` you are missing the quotes here. Is it just typo?

Comment: I did try with quotes, Its not working.

Comment: selectors have to be quoted anyway

Comment: Don't understand why you bind the click event inside an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo** http://fiddle.jshell.net/rG6F9/13/ (click on `varaibles` text and you will see before and after alerts for HTML.

Highlight will work fine here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/8axss/20/ (I have cleaned up your html as well script)

Hiya, multiple things are not correct:

1) `$('#showVariables').click(function()`

2) `.identifier` is a class so use `.`.

3) `identifier` should be placed as the outter most span which was earlier only places for Sample.

Rest please see Jquery and html below.

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
var words = ['Sample', 'count'];
var keywords = ['import', 'public', 'class', 'static', 'void', 'for', 'if', 'else'];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showVariables').click(function() {
        alert($('.identifier').html());
        var wordsHtml = $('.identifier').html();
        $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
            var reg = new RegExp(word, 'g');
            wordsHtml = wordsHtml.replace(reg, '<span class="highlight" style="backgroun-color:yellow;">' + word + '</span>');

        })
           alert(" AFter HTML highlight == " + wordsHtml);
        $('#identifier').html(wordsHtml);
    });


});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="menuDiv"><span id="showVariables" class="button">Variables</span><span id="showKeywords" class="button">Keywords</span></div>
<div id="codeDiv">
<br><span class="keyword">import</span> java.io.*;
<br>
<br><span class="keyword">public</span> <span class="keyword">class</span> <span class="identifier">Sample {

<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="keyword">public</span> <span class="keyword">static</span> <span class="keyword">void</span> main(String args[]) {
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>int</span> <span class="identifier">count</span> = 0;
</span>
```

Comment: I just want to highlight those words which are stored in variables.

Comment: Hiya @AnkurKaushal yep thats what you need innit? along with few fixes with trhe syntax, plz lemme know if I missed anything, `:)` cheerios!

Comment: Have you see my demo @AnkurKaushal There was a small issue in HTML as well `idetifier` span should be the otter most element for whole code see here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rG6F9/15/ `<span class="identifier">Sample {` part in particular compared to yours? lemme know how it goes. **By the way** See demo it does add the highlight in there for reference, cheers!

Comment: @AnkurKaushal I have corrected your HTML as well as Jquery code: and redid some parts ==> http://fiddle.jshell.net/8axss/20/ Please dont forget accpet and upvote the answer, `B-)` cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is there is no "if click" and syntax for selector is also wrong - missing quotes

The "if", for lack of better term, happens only if user does the click

Change:

```
if (#showVariables).click(function(){
```

To

```
$('#showVariables').click(function(){
```

EDIT: Recoded to pass various arrays to same highlight function. Demo uses both arrays "words" and "keywords"

DEMO: http://fiddle.jshell.net/dxPhK/

Still minor problem with reserved word 'class' being pased into regex

```
var words = ['Sample', 'count'];
var keywords = ['import', 'public', /*'class',*/ 'static', 'void', 'for', 'if', 'else'];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showVariables').click(function() {
        $('.identifier').each(function(idx, el) {
            var $el=$(el)
            $el.html(hightLightHtml($el.html(), words, 'red'));
        })
    });
    $('#showKeywords').click(function() {
        $('.keyword').each(function(idx, el) {
           // console.log(idx)
            var $el=$(el)
            $el.html(hightLightHtml($el.html(), keywords, 'yellow'));
        })
    });


});


function hightLightHtml(wordsHtml, wordsArray, highlightClass) {
    $.each(wordsArray, function(idx, word) {
        var reg = new RegExp(word, 'g');
        wordsHtml = wordsHtml.replace(reg, '<span class="' + highlightClass + '" >' + word + '</span>');
    })
    return wordsHtml;
}
```

Comment: OK...you have another selector problem .. there are several class=Identifier but I don't see and id=identifier. DOn't know what element you want this placed in